# how to import python PIL on android and kivy?

Tags: android, python, python-imaging-library, kivy

I want to create an application that takes photos from camera and show thumbnails of them on android. The related part of my code is:

```
from plyer import camera
from PIL import Image
.
.
.
    def take_photo_from_camera(self, x):
        filename = str(random.randint(0, 100000000000)) # create random filenames
        self.camera.take_picture("/storage/sdcard0/MyApp/%s.jpg"%(filename), self.on_success_shot)


    def on_success_shot(self, path):
        #Create a thumbnail of taken photo here using PIL
```

I can use android camera without any problem.
I've added the PIL/pillow to the requirements of the kivy buildozer.spec file

```
requirements = kivy, openssl, futures, requests, plyer, pyjnius, pillow
```

When i want to create an apk with this configuration, the apk package succesfully builds but if i install apk and run on my android phone, i'm getting this error in logcat:

```
I/python  (20188):  Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python  (20188):    File "/home/mnrl/teknik/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 32, in <module>
I/python  (20188):    File "/home/mnrl/teknik/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs/PIL/Image.py", line 67, in <module>
I/python  (20188):  ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.tokerteknik.tokerteknik/files/_applibs/PIL/_imaging.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit
I/python  (20188): Python for android ended.
```

I think the problem related to architecture. I'm using ubuntu 16.04 64 bit and kivy buildozer installs 64 bit libraries with pip while installing requirements.
A similar problem here too: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4095 but there's not any solution.
Briefly how can i import PIL on android with kivy buildozer or how to install 32 bit libraries of PIL on 64 bit system?

Comment: This is probably a bug in python-for-android, are you able to open an issue on the [python-for-android github page](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android), reporting the full build log as well?

Comment: @inclement Yes, I've reported this bug to the python for android github page. I'm going to use pygame instead of pil to resize images, it works for me thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use pygame instead of PIL for basic image manipulation processes.
Add pygame to the buildozer requirements list, it works without any problem.

```
import pygame
picture = pygame.image.load(filepath)
picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (100, 100))
pygame.image.save(picture, "scaled_image.png")
```